# How to pass multiple ids in API delete method using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, rest, api

I m using spring boot 1.5 .I am trying to pass multiple IDs in the DELETE, so I tried to pass a list of Ids and browse them to apply the delete method , but it doesnt word, Please help.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteAlert/{ids}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
ResponseEntity<Void> massiveDelete(@PathVariable List<Long> ids ){
    for (Long id : ids) {
    alertService.deleteAlert(id);}
    return ok().build();
}
```

as a result ,deleting all alerts with selected ids

Answer (score 0):

You could send the IDs as parameters such as `deleteAlert/ids=ID1&ids=ID2&ids=ID3` 
notice that the parameters have the same name 'ids'

Then get them as a list of strings

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteAlert", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
ResponseEntity massiveDelete(@RequestParam("ids") List<String> idsList) 
{ 
   for (String id : idsList) {
     alertService.deleteAlert(Long.parseLong(id));
   }

   return ok().build();
}
```

Comment: than you a lot for your help but I need to get a list of ids from the back end, so I m trying just to find out how to apply on each of the given Id ( type Long ) the method delete ( this one is implemented for just one given id )

Comment: The answer does retrieve a list of ids as a string List. You just need to add the ids as parameters on the front-end `/deleteAlert/ids=[first_id]&ids=[second_id]` I have edited the answer to show how you would apply the ids to your deleteAlert() method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get your problem right, maybe specify what exactly doesn't work.

But IF i get it right, you want to pass a list of ids to a DELETE endpoint.

The way you did it actually works, I have just tested it with curl.

the code:

```java
@Controller
public class ControllerImpl {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteAlert/{ids}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> massiveDelete(@PathVariable List<Long> ids){
        for (Long id : ids) {
            System.out.println(id);
        }
        return ok().build();
    }
}
```

the request: 
`curl -X DELETE "localhost:8080/deleteAlert/1,2"`

the output:

```
2019-09-13 19:15:12.156  INFO 27347 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 27 ms
1
2
```

so the api call works. Then maybe your problem comes from the way you invoke the api?